# Creating a list of given length and sequence from a user in python

Tags: python, list, random, input

If I have a specific list with specific letters, how do I first ask the user to input a random number of sequences they want, then a random number of length of the sequence they want, and then generate a list with that information.

EX:

list = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

number of sequence user wants: 25

length of sequence user wants: 6

output:

```
    sequence 1: BCADAC
    sequence 2: ABCDBA
    sequence 3: DCBADC
    .....
    sequence 25: CABADB
```

Answer (score 0):

On the assumption that you do not care what sequences, or the order of them for which they are returned, you can use `itertools.product()` and `random.sample()` to return a specific amount back to the user.

```
import itertools
import random

data = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

seq = int(input('How many sequences?'))
#25
length = int(input('Length of products?'))
#6

for idx, sequence in enumerate(random.sample(list(itertools.product(data, repeat=length)), seq)):
    print(f'sequence {idx + 1}: {"".join(sequence)}')
```

---

Output:

```
sequence 1: ACBCBB
sequence 2: DAABCC
sequence 3: DADABB
sequence 4: BAADAB
sequence 5: BDDBDA
sequence 6: ACDDBB
sequence 7: CDAAAD
sequence 8: DCDCAA
sequence 9: CCBCBC
....
```

Comment: Of course you could. However `itertools` is a built-in method which is optimized for the use case. No need to reinvent the wheel. Is there a reason you do not want to use this?

Comment: kind of, I need to add restrictions to the results generated from this above function, for example, I need to check whether or not one of the sequences has the same letter three times (BBB, CCC, etc), and if so, remove it from the sequence